# How do I use regex to convert Slack URLs to BB Code?

Tags: javascript, regex, slack, bbcode

I'm trying to use regex to convert Slack's version of markdown formatting to BB Code. I'm stuck on links at the moment. Slack formats like this:

```
<www.url.com|This is the actual text>
<www.url.com>
```

BB Code formats like this:

```
[url=www.url.com]This is the actual text[/url]
[url]www.url.com[/url]
```

I'm dealing with the first type using this (in javascript)

```
string.replace(/\<([\s\S]+)(?=\|)\|([\s\S]*?)\>/gm, "[url=$1]$2[/url]"
```

I'm struggling to make a second rule that will only match text between `<...>` if there isn't a `|` in the string. Can anyone help me out?

Also if there's a neat way of dealing with both options in one go then let me know!

Comment: That's not Markdown. Please only use the [tag:markdown] tag for questions about Markdown.

Comment: Apologies, Slack calls it their version of Markdown but I agree, it is very different!

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```js
const text = `<www.url.com|This is the actual text>
<www.url.com>`;
console.log( text.replace(/<([^<>|]*)(?:\|([^<>]*))?>/g, (x, url, text) => text !== undefined ?
 `[url=${url}]${text}[/url]` : `[url]${url}[/url]`) )
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/33GY2M/1). *Details*:

- `<` - a `<` char (please *NEVER* escape this char in any regex flavor if you plan to match a `<` char)
- `([^<>|]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `<`, `>` and `|`
- `(?:\|([^<>]*))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching one or zero occurrences of a `|` and then any zero or more chars other than `<` and `>` captured into Group 2
- `>` - a `>` char (again, please never escape the `>` literal char in any regex flavor).

Comment: Could you give more info on why <> should not be escaped?

Comment: @anotherGatsby Because it is not a regex special metacharacter and in some regex flavors, `\<` / `\>` are word boundaries. And still a great amount of users think that "regex is universal" and will use the same pattern across languages/environments.

Comment: I knew that they are not special characters but did not know that they were word boundaries in some flavor. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Thanks for this super fast response! I'm just getting my head around your notes to make sure I understand it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Am I right in thinking that this will fail if the URL has any of the non-captured characters in it? (<, > and |)? Hopefully this isn't a common issue but perhaps it could be a problem sometimes. Any ideas?

Comment: @David You cannot have `<` and `>` in a tag. It will be a corrupt code then, and that means no regex can match it. `|` is not a problem, it is optional.

Comment: @David Do you have any test cases that fail? Please update, let know if the current solution is good enough.